# Image não contém uma definição para FromStream

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image

Estou usando um método para converter um *array* de bytes de uma imagem no banco dados em uma imagem porem o código diz que `Image` não contem uma definição para `FromStream()`.

```
private Image ConversaoByteparaImagem(byte[] arraybytes)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(arraybytes);
        Image imagem = Image.FromStream(ms);
        return imagem;
    }
```

Linha onde ocorre o erro:

```
Image imagem = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Comment: O erro é bem claro. Qual o namespace de `Image`?

Comment: ```System.Windows.Controls```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De fato esta classe não tem o método `FromStream()` conforme mostra a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.image?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Precisaria ver o que quer fazer e achar outra solução, mas o erro é claro e isto não pode ser feito. Já a classe do Windows Forms tem esse método, conforme [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Se usá-lo então dá para fazer o que deseja, porém não posso afirmar que é uma boa solução (pode funcionar, mas só entendendo o problema em detalhes para analisar). Usando assim deveria resolver o problema específico (mesmo que cause algum outro):

```
using System.Drawing;
```

provavelmente no lugar de:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
```

Não está funcionando por outros motivos (não tem um dado válido, mas o erro que afirma ter não acontece com o *namespace* correto), assim:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(new byte[1024]));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/KcXHNC). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/78QFq3). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Drawing/ImageFromStream.cs).

Comment: Provavelmente ele está confundindo com a classe `Image` da `System.Drawing`.

Comment: Tentei usar com System.Drawing e ele nem sequer reconhece o Image

Comment: @LINQ de fato deve ser isso, coloquei exemplo mostrando "funcionando" já que ele afirma que o erro persiste.

Comment: tentei o novo codigo mas ele continua dizendo que não contem uma definição

Comment: Eu mostrei funcionando, você não está fazendo o que eu fiz.

Comment: estou fazendo, usei o codigo junto com os namespaces e ainda assim ele continua a informar que não possui definição para FileStream

Comment: Então use o `FromStream()` que era o que você queria usar.

Comment: pelo visto o erro era com a IDE,eu reiniciei o programa e estava sem erros